# RecyclerView doesn't refresh after Firebase update

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a RecyclerView and for each item, you can start the EditActivity (for Result) to update your text with Firebase.

The problem is that when you come back to the RecyclerView, data is not refreshed

Here's code from my adapter :

```
holder.editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent edit_intent = new Intent(holder.authorText.getContext(), EditActivity.class);
                    edit_intent.putExtra("text", textList.get(position).getBody());
                    edit_intent.putExtra("id", textList.get(position).textId);
                    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(edit_intent, 1);
                }
            });

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's code from my EditActivity :

```
edit_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        edit_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        String new_text = edit_text.getText().toString();
        mFirestore.collection("Text").document(text_id).update("body", new_text).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, R.string.changes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("newText", new_text);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else{
                    String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, R.string.error + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                edit_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

How to refresh the RecyclerView and setText with the new Text ?

I would be very grateful for your help :)

Comment: I think `onActivityResult()` needs to go in your `EditActivity` not your adapter

Comment: Buy how do I refresh the RecyclerView from EditActivity ?

Comment: Please also show how you bind the data to the recycler view. Ali Ihsan's solution may work but probably there is a much shorter&cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things you're doing wrong.

1. Pass the clickedItem position to `EditActivity` to update it later on.

   ```
   holder.editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent edit_intent = new Intent(holder.authorText.getContext(), EditActivity.class);
               edit_intent.putExtra("text", textList.get(position).getBody());
               edit_intent.putExtra("id", textList.get(position).textId);
               edit_intent.putExtra("position", position);
               ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(edit_intent, 1);
           }
       });
   ```
2. In `EditActivity`, Save the position in a variable & Return it back with new text

   ```
   setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               edit_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               String new_text = edit_text.getText().toString();
               mFirestore.collection("Text").document(text_id).update("body", new_text).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                       if(task.isSuccessful()){
                           Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, R.string.changes, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           Intent intent = new Intent();
                           intent.putExtra("newText", new_text);
                           //Return the position s well
                           intent.putExtra("position", position);
                           setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                           finish();
                       }
                       else{
                           String error = task.getException().getMessage();
                           Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, R.string.error + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                       mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       edit_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
               });
           }
       });
   ```
3. override `onActivityResult()` in your adaptor's parent activity

   ```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (requestCode == 1) {
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

             String newText = data.getStringExtra("newText");
             int itemPosition = data.getIntExtra("position");

             //Pass these values to adapter through `updateItem` method
               adapter.updateItem(newText, itemPosition);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Define the `updateItem` method inside adapter class

   ```
   public void updateItem(String newData, int index)
   {
     textList.set(index, newData);
     adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
   }
   ```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Comment: You are welcome :) please accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this tool :)